# Current value of "foo" is not the same in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect, use-state, dispatch

I'm working on a project in react and I'm experiencing something I can't solve.

summary:

> I'm setting values to an array called 'concatValue' with a useState inside a useEffect. This works perfectly. Then I want to send this values to redux with a dispatch also in a useEffect. I don't know why there's a mismatch beetween the current value of 'concatValue' and its value inside the useEffect that calls the dispatch.

**for example**:

After 4 setState of 'concatValue' called in the useEffect:

1. concatValue = 50
2. concatValue = 120
3. concatValue = 80
4. concatValue = 30

The current value of 'concatValue' in the useEffect that calls the dispatch function

1. concatValue = undefined
2. concatValue = 50
3. concatValue = 120
4. concatValue = 80

**Here is the code**

```
`const [concatValues, setConcatValues] = useState([])`


  useEffect(()=>{
    const firstGraphSeriesValues = []
    const firstLockedGraphSeriesValues = []
    if(firstGraphSeries && firstLockedGraphSeries){
      firstGraphSeries.forEach((el) => {
         el.data.forEach(d => {
           firstGraphSeriesValues.push(d[1])
         })
       }) 
      firstLockedGraphSeries.forEach((el) => {
         el.data.forEach(d => {
           firstLockedGraphSeriesValues.push(d[1])
         })
       }) 
     }
     `setConcatValues(firstGraphSeriesValues.concat(firstLockedGraphSeriesValues))`          
  },[firstGraphSeries, firstLockedGraphSeries])



 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.callInfos && props.levers.length > 0) {
      dispatch(Actions.setIsLoading())
      const metricsToCall = []
      props.callInfos.forEach((graph) => {
        graph.metrics.forEach((metric) => {
          metricsToCall.push({
            id: metric,
            allCountries: true
          })
        })
      })
      dispatch(
        props.getMapData({
          url: globalConfig.API_GRAPH_METRIC_URL,
          metrics: metricsToCall,
          levers: props.levers,
          callInfos: props.callInfos,
          country: props.country,
          legend: props.legend,
          //pass concatValues to mapDisplay.action --> mapDataHelper if needed
          `allValues: concatValues`
        })
      )
    }
  }, [props.callInfos, props.isUpdating, props.country, props.levers, props.legend])
```

If you have any tips they're more than welcomed!